# Submit form that is located on different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm having some troubles with the system I work on. I want to submit a form that is located on page A after submission but also after a user does something on page B or enters it or leaves it.

I want to make it so that after the user enters or leaves page B the form that is located on page A will be submitted without the user doing anything.

So far I've tried to submit the form from the page B with plain JavaScript and jQuery...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("formID").submit();
</script>
```

... as well as doing the same with jQuery...

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
    jQuery( "#formID" ).submit();
    });
```

I even tried to add an `onClick` function to the form and this function I've placed in page B but it didn't work.

I'm open for ideas or possible fixes.

Comment: are the two not in the same DOM at the same time?

Comment: You can only affect elements that are loaded in to the current DOM. If the `form` is in an unloaded page, you cannot affect it through DOM manipulation.

Comment: If you have opened these pages you can work with php

Comment: There are 2 different .php pages located on the same Server and to get to page B you need to first go to Page A which has a link that directs you to Page B.

Comment: @SilverSurfer do you know any way in which i can make a href on button/link with FORM-SUBMISSION and redirect it to the page with the form.

Comment: Just put the pat/file in action attribute in the form tag

Comment: @SilverSurfer the action attribute of the form is already used and i need it to stay like that, question is if there is a way to make href with submission of the form if a person clicks on it and is on different page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided I understand your question correctly, the simple answer is you can't. JavaScript can only interact with the currently loaded page (it has no awareness of other browser tabs or anything similar, for security reasons).

Since it sounds like you don't require the user's input for the second form (otherwise why would you submit it automatically) then I would look into bringing the second form's data into the first one.

I probably shouldn't even suggest it because it really would be a terrible practice.... but you *could* trigger the second form's submission on the load event of the second page...

```
$(function(){ //in the html of the second page to load
    $('#form2').submit();
});
```

this would cause the user to navigate to the second page, only to have them leave it at the instant of load and would be a terrible user experience.. but would answer the question you asked.

Comment: Yeah that is the only helpful thing someone suggested. I'm giving you a point for that  but i guess i'll try to find other solution, because as you said this one isn't good practice but i'll keep it in mind.

Comment: Is there a way to something like href submit button on Page B ?

Comment: @Richard  I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean, control the url the form submits to, then this approach would respect the "action" attribute of the form in the html on page B and go to that destination.